# make sure hook cron is only run once a day setting

Tags: cron

I'm building a `hook_cron` in my module but I actually don't want it to run at a maximum of once a day.
Is there a Drupal setting for this or do I need to check when the last cron was run and see if that was at least 24 hours ago? How do I do this?

I'm using drupal 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would check the implementation of `hook_cron()` in the [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module.

The exact implementation is [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/cron_example!cron_example.module/function/cron_example_cron/7), it's pretty straightforward!

Basically, you're setting the next execution time (in the example code as `cron_example_next_execution`) of your cron run as the very last step in your `hook_cron()` implementation, and then checking it as the very first thing.

If the variable doesn't exist, then cron will fire off your task, and then set it!

Answer (score 5):

This below code will help to run the cron once in a day

```
function hook_cron() {
$cron_last = variable_get('cron_last');
if ( date('ymd', $cron_last) != date('ymd', time())) {
  //your code here
  variable_set('cron_last', date('ymd', time()));
}  }
```

variable_get('cron_last') is declared in common.inc

Comment: You should not set the cron_last variable to at date formatted, bud time()

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) Module. This offers you a lot of functionality for crons.

Comment: The implementation that OP wants is from within their module.  I don't think Elysia Cron (although AWESOME) will actually solve this use case.

Comment: You're right, but i think the module will anyway help him to control the cron runs ...

Comment: Yes, on a site by site basis, but if OPs module only needs to run it's cron tasks once per day then you shouldn't rely on people having Elysia Cron and then setting it themselves :)

Comment: But you _could_ enforce a dependency on Elysia Cron and implement `hook_cronapi()` instead...

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to add a  dependency  though,  when the functionality is already in Drupal  core =/

Comment: Yep fair point @Chapabu it's just an option, and I guess if this is a custom module and Elysia is already installed it'd be an easier one

Comment: I'm already building my own hook_cron implementation adding the cron interval in my module would keep it simpler ( don't let users or even admin change it ) especially since this module's cron needs to do exactly the same on every site I install this. But maybe someone else that stumbles on this question will have more use for your answer.